# sonarqube java api to fetch all the Issues/Violations for a project

Tags: sonarqube

I am using the sonar web api to query the sonar server for violations. Is there a java code to fetch all the Issues/Violations of a particular project in sonarqube? Please, any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you've found the answer to this question by now. However, I'll go ahead and answer this one. There are two ways of fetching all the issues of a particular project.

1. Using the webservice sonarqube exposes.
   http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392181#WebService/api/issues-GetaListofIssues
2. Using a sonar plugin
   How to code a custom sonar plugin?
   https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example

How to get all the issues-
Use 'ProjectIssues' BatchComponent to list all the issues using org.sonar.api.issue.ProjectIssues.issues()

Use **@DependsUpon(DecoratorBarriers.ISSUES_TRACKED)** annotation on your decorator. This will make sure that the decorator is executed once issues are tracked as stated in the documentation.

Extract from DecoratorBarriers class:

```
    /**
     * This barrier is after {@link #ISSUES_ADDED}. The decorators that need to list all issues must be declared
     * after this barrier : {@code @DependsUpon(value=DecoratorBarriers.ISSUES_TRACKED)}
     *
     * @since 3.6
     */
    String ISSUES_TRACKED = "END_OF_VIOLATION_TRACKING";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer :). I was under the impression that this question remained unnoticed. I was eventually able to figure out the webservice api and developed a custom sonar plugin for generating pdf reports for ant based projects. Now my question, is there a way to fetch all the PMD violations or checkstyle violations or findbugs violations of a project using the sonar webservice api. Please let me know. Thanks a lot :).

Comment: Decorators have been deprecated since 5.x :-(